Ollama running with Github actions
How do you configure a github actions yml file to serve ollama and to load it with a base model (such as llama3), ideally as a service.  Be great if we can see the progress in the logs as the models load.
Fundamentally when I run locally i do something like this
> ollama pull llama2
> ollama serve


Has anyone had success with this?
They have recently created a docker image that hopefully we can leverage (link to image description)

I don't know anything about the Docker part, but actually you can just install and run Ollama like you would do on your computer.
I just tested the following GitHub Action workflow successfully:
name: Ollama
'on':
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  summarize:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Install ollama
      run: curl -fsSL https://ollama.com/install.sh | sh
    - name: Run ollama
      run: |
        ollama serve &
        ollama pull phi3:mini
    - name: Call ollama API
      run: |
        curl -d '{"model": "phi3:mini", "stream": false, "prompt":"Whatever I say, asnwer with Yes"}' http://localhost:11434/api/generate

This took rouhgly 1 minute to finish. With larger models it probably take a bit longer.
Hope this helps a bit.
